# Simulate a button click within the application (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Good day,

In my application, I have `Private Sub btnSendSMS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSendMessage.Click` in my program.

I would like to simulate a button click of the above within my other sub (an SMS receive detector) when an SMS is received.

How do I do this? I know this is not the best way of doing things but just for the sake of learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call the [`Button.PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx#Y0) method:

```
btnSendSMS.PerformClick()
```

Comment: That is perfect but how do you do that without making a sound? My system seems to always make a sound.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the function directly.

```
btnSendSMS_Click(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you put the code in a seperate method

```
Private Sub SendSMS()
    ' do your thing
End Sub
```

and in your button event handler, call that method.

```
Private Sub btnSendSMS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSendMessage.Click
    Call SendSMS()
End Sub
```

Now you can call `SendSMS()` anywhere in your class without having to do something funky like simulating button clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Or in case of using VB in WPF:

```
Dim peer As New ButtonAutomationPeer(btnSendSMS)
Dim invokeProv As IInvokeProvider = TryCast(peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke), IInvokeProvider)
invokeProv.Invoke()
```